# Swagger UI - Limit enum array to only a single submittable value

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am creating a pre-defined list of items that I would like the user to select from within Swagger UI and I found the layout for the most part, however with the way I have it setup, the user can submit multiple values in the enum whereas I only want the user to be able to select a single value. Any recommendations would be appreciated. Right now the user can select from "available", "pending", or "sold". I have included the "required" parameter so I am handling the case where the user needs to select something at least, now I just need to restrict it to only a single value.

Swagger UI config:

```
{
            "name": "event",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "events that need to be considered for filter",
            "required": true,
            "style": "form",
            "explode": true,
            "allowEmptyValue": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "available",
                "enum": [
                  "available",
                  "pending",
                  "sold"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrict the user to only the values your looking for. You need to loop through their response against your accepted response. If acceptable and matches' your parameters, move on, else select a different response.

Comment: Yeah this may be the way to go. I thought there may have been a way to restrict this within the swagger config file, however i can't seem to find how.

Comment: fairly certain the config file is loaded into memory when you start the server/service or whatever your working with, with that being said, the config file is static rather than dynamic. It's your code that is dynamic.